# View transition from UICollectionView cell to UIViewController by expanding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a collection view and I want to expand cell when clicked. Cell should be expanded to full screen and change to another `UIViewController`. I want transition to be smooth however, I don't know how to change collectionview cell to `UIViewController` via expanding it. I implemented custom `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` and `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`. What should I write in `animateTransition` in order to achieve what I wanted?

Comment: try this method - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: I know how to trigger animation but I do not know how to write animation.

Comment: try modalTransitionStyle and modalPresentationStyle